# How can I reset cocos2d game state?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am not entirely sure how to properly phrase this question so I'll explain what happens. I have a cocos2d game, and after I exit the game and start it again, it starts at the exact same point. Its as if it is "saving."

Is there any way to prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this like here will resolve your problem:
http://maniacdev.com/2010/07/screw-multi-tasking-how-to-make-your-ios-4-apps-exit-for-real/

However, if it doesn't - I did have this problem a few times.

- Try this first.  Goto Buld and select Clean all targets.  Uninstall your app from the device.  Reboot your device and restart xcode.  Rebuild & reinstall your app on the device and see it that fixed it.
- If not then wipe and reset your device to default so it was like brand new with the most recent OS.  Reinstall your app and try again.
- If still not fixed, try removing xcode and reinstalling it with the newest version. Make sure to clean all targets and rebuild your app.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could reset your game upon resume:

In your application's delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    if (!_appIsPaused) {
        NSLog(@"app Became Active");
        ....set a state variable here....
    }
}
```

Then in your application's tick method(a method that is ran every frame) check the value of the state variable in your delegate and run a reset method to reset your application to the beginning.  Alternatively, upon resume you could pop an alert (which would pause the app) and ask the player if they want to start from the beginning or resume where they left off.